# Rackspace cloud files client side uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rackspace-cloud

I am using Rackspace cloud files as my CDN. My app is image heavy and right now, all image are being uploaded to my server and from there being uploaded to cloud files.

This I think is redundant and it's waste of my server resources. I think a better solution would be for me to give the client a URL to upload and then client can upload to the URL (bypassing my server completely) and telling the server everythings done.

I am wondering if this is possible using cloud files and how it can be done. I am using Rails on server side btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [the `FormPost` feature](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/FormPost-d1a555.html) of Rackspace Cloud Files.

> FormPost lets you offer your website audience a way to upload objects to your Cloud Files account through a web form.

Answer (score 0):

A CDN Container has four URIs associated with it: iOS Streaming, Streaming, HTTPS and HTTP.

Can't you use the, say, HTTPS URI to allow your clients to upload directly to the Container?